# Tried to add a class to a list of classes from a base class in a inherited class, but got error CS0119

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

> "CS0119 'something' is a type, which is not valid in the given
> context"

Is what I got when I tried to add the inherited class to a list from the base class. What am I doing wrong?.

```
public class stuff{
     public List <stuff> someStuff = new List<stuff>();
}
class something : stuff{
     public something(){
          stuff.Add(something); //error
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about the difference of classes and instances / objects.

Comment: This been asked before, its just something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141525/c-sharp-listt-adding-inherited-items)

Comment: As an aside, it's a really good idea to follow .NET naming conventions even for sample code in questions.

Comment: @Getwrong: No, that question is about something entirely different, in terms of the error that the OP is reporting here. (Sure, they're both trying to do the same thing, but the questions being asked are different.)

Comment: So what about the answer ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) instead of your class names, so change your code to something like this:

```
class something : stuff
{
    public something()
    {
        someStuff.Add(new something());
    }
}
```

Please note that your new instance of your `List<stuff>` is called `someStuff` which accepts a new instance of your `something` class which would be something like `new something()`.

As @Jon also mentioned in the comments, *it's a really good idea to follow .NET naming conventions* always, so in your  case I would suggest the following names instead:

```
public class Stuff
{
     public List<Stuff> someStuff = new List<Stuff>();
}

class Something : Stuff
{
    public Something()
    {
        someStuff.Add(new Something());
    }
}
```